# passing an array as an argument; Setting up Array in Java with user input with Scanner Class

Tags: java, arrays, methods, user-input

I am trying to take user input, place it into my array, display the array and then print all the values larger than the "n" values the user provides.  I think I am close, but I can't get the user input to go to the array. I keep getting an error in eclipse when I call the method (main at very bottom) the "arrayValues" *cannot be resolved to a variable*:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

`import java.util.Scanner;`

`public class LargerThanN {`

```
 //initialize n
static int n;

static int arraySize;

//setup the array
static int [] integerArray = new int [] {};

public static void printGreaterThanN(int[] integerArray, int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            if (integerArray[i]>n) { 
                System.out.println(integerArray[i]);

            }
    } 

}

public static int[] fillArrayWithUserInt() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How big will the array be?");
    int arraySize = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // clears rest of input, including carriage return

    int[] integerArray = new int[arraySize];

    System.out.println("Enter the " + arraySize + " numbers now.");

        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
        integerArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    return integerArray;

    }





/**
 * This method prints the array to the standard output
 * @param array
 */
private static void displayArray( int[] integerArray) {

    for (int i = `0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(integerArray[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

`public static void main(String[] args) {`

```
        int [] array ;

        array = fillArrayWithUserInt();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        fillArrayWithUserInt();

        displayArray(array);

         System.out.println("To which number would you like to compare the rest? Your n value is: ");

            n = sc.nextInt();

        printGreaterThanN(array, n);
```

but now my output looks like:

How big will the array be?

4

Enter the 4 numbers now.

1 2 3 4

How big will the array be?

3

Enter the 3 numbers now.

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

To which number would you like to compare the rest? Your n value is:

2

3

4

Comment: You never declare `arrayValues`. Maybe you forgot something?

Comment: there are two arrays declared one in `printGreaterThanN()` and the `fillArrayWithUserInt()` specify which one you will be using, or maybe remove the first function declared since you are initializing the array, it's size and values in the fill func.

Comment: I try to declare arrayValues in the method, but then it gives me a flag for a duplicate variable

Comment: @FishingCode so should i delete the int [] integerArray fromFillArrayWithUserInt()?

Comment: if you delete it there, there then you still would have to initialize it within the function then or just remove the first function, am not seeing the value of it?

Comment: So the greaterThanN method I need to pass both the array and int n. So I cannot get rid of that, if I am understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heads up, the following code does nothing in java...

```java
public void set(int n, int value) {
    n = value;
}
```

You seem to written code like this in many functions where a value should be returned.

For example, the function definition :

`static void fillArrayWithUserInt(int[] integerArray, int arraySize, int arrayValues, int n)`

Should really be written as :

`static int[] fillArrayWithUserInt()`

It could be implemented as follows

```java
public static int[] fillArrayWithUserInt() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How big will the array be?");
    int arraySize = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // clears rest of input, including carriage return

    int[] integerArray = new int[arraySize];

    System.out.println("Enter the " + arraySize + " numbers now.");

    System.out.println("What are the numbers in your array?");

    for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
        integerArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    return integerArray;
}
```

The above function will ask the user for the array size. Create the array with the given size. Then prompt the user to fill the array with the correct number of values. The array created in this process is then returned.

All you must handle differently now is finding the value to compare. This must be done outside the `fillArrayWithUserInt` function.

Like so :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] array = fillArrayWithUserInt();
    displayArray(array);
    System.out.println("To which number would you like to compare the rest? Your n value is: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    printGreaterThanN(array, n);
}
```

Lastly, you should not need to declare any static variables at the top of your class.

These lines can all be deleted  :

```java
 //initialize n
static int n;

static int arraySize;

//setup the array
static int [] integerArray = new int [] {};
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  So If I move the n comparison to the main, however, I am not returning my values larger than it when I run it.  (updating code in original post)

Comment: Well the `fill` function will only create an array with the specified number of elements. It's your job in `main` to use that value created...

Comment: Try adding `array = fillArrayWithUserInt()` to `main`. Then using `array` in the function calls after...

Comment: The way my greaterThanN is setup, shouldn't that print my values when I call it? You are the most helpful person on this website so far, so I very much applaud you for that.

Comment: Yes, but you aren't passing any values in currently.

Comment: sorry editing top code because I can't format properly in the comments

Comment: Ok, edited. It runs through my questions twice now but gets me there in the end.

Comment: You have `fillArrayUserInt` twice in your `main` method... look at my updated `main` method.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough!  You have been incredibly helpful.  How did you get so good at this?  Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution check it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargerThanN {
    static int[] integerArray = null;
    static int n ;

    public static void printGreaterThanN() {

        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            if (integerArray[i] > n) {
                System.out.println(integerArray[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void fillArrayWithUserInt() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How big will the array be?");
        int arraySize = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); // clears rest of input, including carriage return

        integerArray = new int[arraySize];

        System.out.println("Enter the " + arraySize + " numbers now.");

        System.out.println("What are the numbers in your array?");

        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            integerArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("To which number would you like to compare the rest? Your n value is: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

    }

    /**
     * This method prints the array to the standard output
     * 
     * @param array
     */
    private static void displayArray() {

        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(integerArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fillArrayWithUserInt();

        displayArray();

        printGreaterThanN();

    }
}
```